# Configure Postfix to Use Gmail SMTP on Ubuntu

Tags: smtp, gmail, postfix-mta

I'm using [this online guide here](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/) to enable
simple mail sending from linux (ubuntu) terminal
with postfix through some gmail account.
I've done the steps listed there:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

And add these lines:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Then edit this file:

```
vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

To add the lines like it says in the guide:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    USERNAME@gmail.com:PASSWORD
```

(Of course with my own mail and password) then finally:

```
sudo chmod 400 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

And then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

When I try to send a simple mail nothing happens:

```
echo "Test mail from postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" you@example.com
```

(Of course here too with some other valid email)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need validate certificates to avoid running into error.

Try with:

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

If you run into issues with above command, try rename the certificate to:
 `thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem` in above command.

And now, reaload the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Comment: Yes it works!! I've used: thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Issue may be related to application passwords. For example I can't use my gmail on old clients with my current password. You may want to create "[Application Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)".

Or Enabling [less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps) can help. (Most probably this is the solution)

For managing app paswords:
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Extra info: [Use Gmail as your SMTP Server – even when using 2-factor authentication (2-step verification)](https://galleryserverpro.com/use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server-even-when-using-2-factor-authentication-2-step-verification/)

Comment: Thanks, less secure apps were enabled before, so this is not it. It looks like 2 step authentication might make the whole thing even more complicated, so I'd rather avoid that -- The weird thing is that I did the exact same thing once on an old computer ...